# how to match value of string in arraylist

Tags: android

How to match string with `ArrayList` and check if is found or is not found I'm getting list of dates from json and save in `ArrayList`. How will I match `ArrayList` with string to check `ArrayList` contains string value or not?

string sampledate;
  sampledate="26/5/2013";

```
    static ArrayList<String> Vacation_Date = new ArrayList<String>();



            JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);

        status = json3.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school = json3.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) school.getJSONObject(k);
                Category_ID.add((long) k);

                Vacation_Date.add(jb.getString("date"));
                }

      if(Vacation_Date.equals(sampledate)
  {
      //dosomething   
         }





         idid like this  
            if(Vacation_Date.equals(mydate))

        //in debug mode vocation is this    [2013-09-29, 2013-09-25, 2013-10-05, 2013-09-27]

   //   String   mydate;
 value of mydate in debug mode     mydate=///2013-09-19=///2013-09-19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!Vacation_Date.contains(jb.getString("date")))
{
  Vacation_Date.add(jb.getString("date"));
     //Do your stuff here .
}
```

Comment: i mean check Vacation_Datearray list contain sampledate

Comment: @smartguy yes you can use `arraylist.contain("valuetoCheck")` for checking if arraylist contains that value or not, Please explain if im am wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You can check by this:

```
for(int=0; i<Vacation_Date.size();i++){

if(Vacation_Date.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(sampledate)){

  // do your stuff here
}

}
```

Comment: first you have to get your string from array list and then convert it to simple date format and after that compare the string with your date string